# Checkbox toggle field with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Try show/hide a field when checked a checkbox.
How can i do this with jQuery?

Thats my code:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox " name="billing_wcj_checkout_field_2" id="billing_wcj_checkout_field_2" value="1">

<input type="text" class="input-text " name="billing_eu_vat_number" id="billing_eu_vat_number" placeholder="EU VAT Number" value="">

<script>
    jQuery(function() {
            jQuery('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
                jQuery(this).find('#billing_eu_vat_number_field').toggle(!this.checked);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: For one thing, the id you are searching for in the jqeury is incorrect, you have add `_field` to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox " name="billing_wcj_checkout_field_2" id="billing_wcj_checkout_field_2" value="1">

<input type="text" class="input-text " name="billing_eu_vat_number" id="billing_eu_vat_number" placeholder="EU VAT Number" style="display:none;" value="">
```

### JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#billing_wcj_checkout_field_2").click(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
      $("#billing_eu_vat_number").show();
    }else{
      $("#billing_eu_vat_number").hide();
    }
  });

});
```

Working pen link

[enter link description here](https://codepen.io/smitraval27/pen/YaZBVN)

Comment: Please approve the answer if it helped. :) Thanks @Tuxy

Comment: Ok, i'm sorry! forget :-/

Comment: No issue. Thanks @Tuxy :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like that:

```js
    jQuery(function() {
            jQuery('.input-checkbox').change(function() {
                jQuery('#billing_eu_vat_number').toggle();
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox " name="billing_wcj_checkout_field_2" id="billing_wcj_checkout_field_2" value="1">

<input type="text" class="input-text " name="billing_eu_vat_number" id="billing_eu_vat_number" placeholder="EU VAT Number" value="">
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. At this moment i used the code from Smit Raval , but i'm happy also with your answer. So i can learn a lot how coding 'best practice' in jQuery :-)